# How to fix 'Api calls being made multiple times' - a very strange problem

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes

In my API, I am using nodeJS, expressJS. It is a microservices based architecture. I have used express-generator to create this API. Following is my routing structure. I have a middleware and the normal routing as given below. '*' is being used for regex.

```
// routing goes here for the middleware
app.use('/api/*/', (req, res, next) => {
  // send it to middleware
  middleware.entry(req, res, next);
});

// rest of the routing goes here, after satisfying the access conditions from middleware
app.use('/api/*/review', reviewRouter);
```

Middleware entry code is following. It calls auth service and confirms if the request has access to the route or not.

```
const entry = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // let's get the auth url
        const url = process.env.AUTH_URL + req.originalUrl;

        console.log('review: ', req.body);
        let response = {};

        switch (req.method) {
            case 'GET':
                response = await fetch.get(url, {
                    method: 'get',
                    headers: req.headers
                });
                break;
            case 'POST':
                response = await fetch.get(url, {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: req.headers,
                    body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
                });
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                response = await fetch.get(url, {
                    method: 'put',
                    headers: req.headers,
                    body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
                });
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                response = await fetch.get(url, {
                    method: 'delete',
                    headers: req.headers
                });
                break;
        }

        if (response.code === 200) {
            // we got the successful result, the access is good
            if (response.data.user) {
                req.user = response.data.user;
            }
            next();
        }
        else {
            // error
            const error = response.error;
            return responseHelper.error(res, error, error.code ? error.code : codes.ERROR);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('e: ', error);
        responseHelper.error(res, error, error.code ? error.code : codes.ERROR);
    }
};
```

Coming back to the problem. Everything works great. This is a prod and working pretty good for about a year now. Yesterday, after installing some updates, I restarted my server. In between, something happened which multiplied the api requests. For example, when I called /api/shopping/review, ideally it should submit 1 request to middleware. But it was submitting about 200+ requests to middleware. It was strange. Somehow this section:

```
// routing goes here for the middleware
app.use('/api/*/', (req, res, next) => {
  // send it to middleware
  middleware.entry(req, res, next);
});
```

was triggered 100s of times. It happened only once, and after restarting, it went back to fine. But it left me wondering what can be the issue for this request duplicity. Can someone please help me in understanding in what circumstances this behavior can be reproduced? What might be the issue? This is important because if I don't find the reason behind this behavior, there is always a threat to the application if it comes back to haunt me. Any suggestions will really be appreciated.